# Format a table to expand over 8 columns

Tags: html

I've been practicing formatting tables individually by cell but am now having problems when I want to have a singular header expand over 8 columns (Supporting Services over [Program Services, General and Administrative, Fundraising, Total]).

I'd like to be able to expand over those subtopics, but am not sure about how to go about it.

```html
 <table style="height: 701px; width: 794px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">Supporting Services</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">2018</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22.8px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22.8px;">Program Services</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22.8px;">General and Administrative</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22.8px;">Fundraising</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;Total</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22.8px;">Total Expenses</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22.8px;">Total Expenses</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 82px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 82px;">Salaries, payroll taxes and employee benefits</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 82px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 82px;">2,683,469</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 82px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 82px;">343,518</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 82px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;222,945</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 82px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;566,463</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 82px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 82px;">3,249,932</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 82px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 82px;">1,854,290</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 42px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Professional fees</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">150,767</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">132,627</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">3,739&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">136,366&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">287,133</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">276,085</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 42px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Publications and research&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">20,628</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">984</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">-&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">984&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">21,612</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">12,927</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 42px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Information technology</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">30,266</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">27,699</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">35&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">27,734&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">58,000</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">45,683</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Travel</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">93,289</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">1,104</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">-&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">1,104&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">94,393</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">72,741</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Occupancy</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">273,543</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">35,017</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">22,726&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">57,743&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">331,286</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">100,116</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Events</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">9,600</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">7,294</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">5,183&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">12,477&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">2,149,145</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">24,224</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 42px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Office supplies</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">26,375</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">3,494</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">2,191&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">5,685&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">32,060</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">51,896</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Insurance</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">38,551</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">8,242</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">-&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">8,242&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">46,793</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">8,914</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Advertising&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">11,207</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">495</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">150&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">645&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">11,852</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">5,035</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Bank fees</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">2,762</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">3,875</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">-&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">3,875&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">6,637</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">662</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Miscellaneous</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">10,943</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">3,610</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">177&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">3,787</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">14,730</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">11,539</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Depreciation</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">56,887</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">7,283</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">4,726&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">12,009&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">68,896</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">12,946</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 62px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 62px;">Total Expenses, 2018</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">3,408,287</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 62px;">575,242</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 62px;">261,872&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">837,114&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 62px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 62px;">4,245,401</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 62px;">
    <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 62px;">Total Expenses, 2017</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">1,879,275</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
    <td style="width: 95.2px; height: 62px;">422,329</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
    <td style="width: 79.2px; height: 62px;">175,454&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
    <td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">597,783&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 20px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 78.4px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">$</td>
    <td style="width: 75.2px; height: 62px;">2,477,058</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colspan="100"` to span over multiple columns (setting it to a lot will automatically set it to the maximum amount of columns to span over).

But just a tip. Learn some more style attributes (padding and such) and css to format your tables. This just looks unreadable and a lot of work to make.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add some Table Headings

For example:

```
 <tr>
    <th colspan="10">Supporting Services</th>
    <th colspan="3">2018</th>
    <th colspan="3">2017</th>
 </tr>
```

```html
<table style="height: 701px; width: 794px;">
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <th colspan="10">Supporting Services</th>
    <th colspan="3">2018</th>
    <th colspan="3">2017</th>
 </tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22.8px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22.8px;">Program Services</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22.8px;">General and Administrative</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22.8px;">Fundraising</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;Total</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22.8px;">Total Expenses</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22.8px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22.8px;">Total Expenses</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 82px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 82px;">Salaries, payroll taxes and employee benefits</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 82px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 82px;">2,683,469</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 82px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 82px;">343,518</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 82px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;222,945</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 82px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;566,463</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 82px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 82px;">3,249,932</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 82px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 82px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 82px;">1,854,290</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 42px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Professional fees</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">150,767</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">132,627</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">3,739&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">136,366&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">287,133</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">276,085</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 42px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Publications and research&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">20,628</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">984</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">-&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">984&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">21,612</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">12,927</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 42px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Information technology</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">30,266</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">27,699</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">35&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">27,734&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">58,000</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">45,683</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Travel</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">93,289</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">1,104</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">-&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">1,104&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">94,393</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">72,741</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Occupancy</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">273,543</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">35,017</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">22,726&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">57,743&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">331,286</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">100,116</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Events</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">9,600</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">7,294</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">5,183&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">12,477&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">2,149,145</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">24,224</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 42px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 42px;">Office supplies</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">26,375</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 42px;">3,494</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 42px;">2,191&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 42px;">5,685&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 42px;">32,060</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 42px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 42px;">51,896</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Insurance</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">38,551</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">8,242</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">-&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">8,242&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">46,793</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">8,914</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Advertising&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">11,207</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">495</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">150&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">645&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">11,852</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">5,035</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Bank fees</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">2,762</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">3,875</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">-&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">3,875&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">6,637</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">662</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Miscellaneous</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">10,943</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">3,610</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">177&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">3,787</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">14,730</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">11,539</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">Depreciation</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">56,887</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">7,283</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">4,726&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">12,009&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">68,896</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">12,946</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 22px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 22px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 62px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 62px;">Total Expenses, 2018</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">3,408,287</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 62px;">575,242</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 62px;">261,872&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">837,114&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 62px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 62px;">4,245,401</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 62px;">
<td style="width: 155.2px; height: 62px;">Total Expenses, 2017</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 14.4px; height: 62px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">1,879,275</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
<td style="width: 95.2px; height: 62px;">422,329</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
<td style="width: 79.2px; height: 62px;">175,454&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 17.6px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;$</td>
<td style="width: 68px; height: 62px;">597,783&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 78.4px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 24px; height: 62px;">$</td>
<td style="width: 75.2px; height: 62px;">2,477,058</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```